# Can I position and size a linear-gradient within the background?

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients

I have been wrestling with a layered CSS background today. I am trying to have three layers (from foreground to background):

- an image
- a black bar (emulated with a `linear-gradient`
- a gradient overlay

This is my CSS for the element:

```css
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #00000000 0%, #00000000 15%, #000000ff calc(100% - 40rem)), linear-gradient(to right, #000000ff 0%, #000000ff 100%),  url("../assets/images/bg-1080-1920.png");
  background-size: cover, 40rem 4rem, auto;
  background-position: top left, 0rem 3rem, top left;
```

For some reason, the black bar I am trying to insert takes over the whole screen even though I have set `background-position` and `background-size` properties. After looking at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#working_with_gradients), I believe I have followed all of the rules. It does indicate that it may be a browser issue, but adding `-webkit` to the property name didn't help either (I am using a Chromium browser while I code).

MDN doesn't mention gradients on the `background-position` page and it still takes over the screen even if I remove that property. I have also tried entering sizes in `px` to see if it was an issue using the `rem` unit. Both to no avail.

Is there something obviously wrong with the property values? Or am I crazy.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to archieve here, pls provide a minimal reproduction.

Comment: I also cannot find a definition which states whether (or not) linear-gradient can be sized and experiments seem to prove it can't. While I can see a workaround for your particular case, could you say what you'd like your first linear gradient to do as it has 8 digit color codes and also would seem to overwrite everything else?. Or would you like it as is but with opacity<1?

Comment: @AHaworth the trick is the `background-repeat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never forget `background-repeat`

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(to right, #00000000 0%, #00000000 15%, #000000ff calc(100% - 40rem)), 
    linear-gradient(to right, #000000ff 0%, #000000ff 100%), 
    url("https://picsum.photos/id/1069/800/800");
  background-size: cover, 40rem 4rem, auto;
  background-position: top left, 0rem 3rem, top left;
  background-repeat:no-repeat; /* this is important !! */
}
```

Comment: This should really be included within the MDN docs in the section relating to sizing linear-gradients. I'm gonna put in a pull request to update the page with this information. Thank you!

Comment: @SimpleProgrammer not really. The issue you faced is particular because your gradient is a solid color so you cannot notice the repetition. If it was a gradient with two colors you can easily see the correct size and the repetition and is some case the repetition is wanted (and it's the default behavior)

Comment: Absolutely agree. However, SO was the last place I came to for advice on this issue. All of the devs I spoke to up until that point had wildly varying opinions on whether this could be done at all. That tells me that the `background-repeat` property was a blind spot for many others, too.